# In which cases multiple hostnames are set/uses with sudo

Tags: sudo, visudo

My computer has a label/hostname, let's say `learn_linux`.

In the `/etc/sudoers`  the format is:

```
user  ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL
%group ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL
```

the first field ->  `user, %group` is referring to the user/group that get the privileges

the second field -> `ALL` , is one or a list of hostnames on which sudo entry will be effective

---

Let's say that the Linux computer has the hostname `learn_linux`

The computer(windows) from which I'm trying to connect remotely to Linux has hostname `windows_learn`

1. in the `/etc/sudoers` I have:

   `user1 learn_linux=(ALL:ALL)  ALL`

If I'm connecting from my Windows machine remotely using SSH and `user1`, it means I can't use sudo ?

viceversa

2. in the `/etc/sudoers` I have:

   `user1 learn_linux, learn_windows=(ALL:ALL)  ALL`

If I'm connecting from my Windows machine remotely using SSH and `user1`, it means I can use `sudo` ?

3. in the `/etc/sudoers` I have:

   `user1 localhost=(ALL:ALL)  ALL`

I'm totally blocked of using `sudo` for the user or `localhost` can be used as a substitute for 'linux_learn' ?

4. What if I have:

`user1 some_text=(ALL:ALL)  ALL`, can I use `sudo` for user1 from the same computer

My dilemma is if the hostname is referring also to computers that connect remotely to the Linux computer, or only to the Linux computer hostname.

Comment: Host names are used by large organizations with multiple system administrators.  They maintain o e master file and distribute it to multiple hosts. There is a brief discussion here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71684/the-host-variable-in-etc-studies and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Harden_with_Sudo_Example . Can you clarify what you are asking ?

Comment: In other words, the `hostname` is only relevant when you want to maintain just one single `sudoers` file (at some central place) and copy that file to multiple hosts.

Comment: @PerlDuck - yes